# PHP Query the name of SQL table containing a specific value

Tags: php, mysqli

I am building an online store and I am using cookies for my shopping cart. 
All of my tables contain a Part_ID column. 
When an item is added to the shopping cart the Part_ID and quantity is stored as part of the cookie. 
Currently all Part_ID values are in the format of "Table_Name-/Part_ID".

This was an ugly workaround I implemented in building the store so I could use the Table_Name to query all the necessary values of each part in the shopping cart (Name, price, weight. etc)

I would like to be able to remove the table name from the Part_ID field.

My question is how can I

A) Execute a query that will return only the name of the table containing the specific Part_ID that is stored in the cookie and read by the shopping cart?

Or

B) Execute query that will return the row containing the Part_ID out of all tables in the database.

Procedural mysqli solution is preferable.
Thanks in advance

Comment: So why have you designed a database structure with multiple parts tables in the first place?

Comment: there are 26 tables so far, 26 different product types, 26 different sets of specifications that needed to be listed in the tables.

Comment: Single product table, that links to a specificationset table

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion and will consider that in future projects. However at this point that method would require me to restructure my entire database of over 500 items and perform queries from multiple tables to render a single row on my product pages. Do you know of a way to do what I am trying to do? If not It'll be easier for me to just leave the table name in the part ID

Comment: It shouldn't require multiple queries; just queries using JOINs, but short of spending time actually designing and writing the system for you, I can't give you a brief answer.... your approach is badly designed and will give you a lot of headaches in the future (you're already finding them now, with this question), and you really should try redesigning your database structure properly now (irrespective of how many parts you already have in the database, which can always be migrated to a better structure)